# Laravel 4 Carbon trailing data error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, php-carbon

I am getting the following error when retrieving a timestamp field from my database and converting it to json for response.

**InvalidArgumentException
Trailing data**

the table has a created_at field which is a postgres timestampz field i.e timestamp with timezone I guess.

and even if I access the field via $column->created_at

it's throwing that error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `getDateFormat` in your Models to override the default format :

```
protected function getDateFormat()
{
    return 'Y-m-d H:i:sO';
}
```

The method `getDateFormat` is protected in Laravel 5.5 and below, but in the 5.6 it's public and it's mentioned in the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade#upgrade-5.6.0) on the Eloquent section :
[image]

Comment: In my case Laravel threw a error saying that `getDateFormat` should be public

Comment: This happens when you use Carbon with Postgres since Postrges gives us the milliseconds. In case you are using TIME WITH TIMEZONES in Postgres then this is the correct format `Y-m-d H:i:s.uO`